# How to verify css attribute with Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am actually looking at selenium IDE for testing many parts of websites, so I am new at this.
I have been looking for verifying css styles attributes (for example font color, background color and such) of elements of a web page.

I found many documentation using the command "VerifyAttribute", but those are from 3 to 6 years ago, and the actual version does not have this command, and I can't seem to find any equivalent.

I have tried the "VerifyElementPresent" and such commands, but the test always pass although I have added css attributes (like background-color=#333333), because the element is present in the page, whatever i write in the "Value" box.

So my questions are:

1- Is it possible to verify css styles attributes and values with Selenium IDE?

2- If yes, which command should I use, and how to write a correct expected value?

3- If not possible with Selenium IDE, could you refer me to another plugin (related to selenium IDE?) or software that I could use to test css styles?

Thank you in advance for your help!